# Scala: Projecting negative elements in DenseMatrix to 0

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

In python, if I want to set negative entries from a matrix A,
I could do:

```
    A = np.max(A, 0)
```

Is there a similar method in Scala? I have a matrix with Breeze DenseMatrix type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`breeze.linalg.max(A, 0.0)`

(Using 0.0 instead of 0 is important, because Breeze doesn't automatically promote scalar types.)